# Files app has some screenshots from Safari that wasn’t screenshot

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture, mobile-safari

I have an iPhone 11 with the latest update and everything. But recently I noticed in my Files, there are several long screenshots from some sites I frequent, specifically comic websites and art websites. Sometimes I tend to press and hold the screen instead of scrolling and I suspect as a result, this has been happening. I don't know how to disable this feature.

I tried looking the Accesibility settings but nothing seems to stand out. If I missed something, I'm not sure. Can someone please help me disable this function? I don't want to be accused of stealing people's work and getting banned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a Safari setting.  Search for `Full Page Screenshot` and turn it off.

Or the `Back Tap` is set to Screenshot.  Turn it to Off.

> You can take a screenshot with what appears to be magic. Back Tap, an accessibility feature introduced in iOS 14, allows you to tap the back of your iPhone to perform a certain action. If you have an iPhone 8 or higher, you can set this feature to take screenshots for you.
>
> Open Settings > Accessibility > Touch > Back Tap and choose either Double Tap or Triple Tap. Set the action to Screenshot, and then you can double- or triple-tap to take a screen capture.

From [pcmag](https://au.pcmag.com/apple-ios/95247/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-your-iphone-ipad-or-apple-watch)

Comment: Many thanks! My Back Tap is switched off so there's no chance of that. Where can I access Full Page Screenshot? It doesn't show up as a result when searching and I can't access it under the Safari tab in Settings either.